# How to access httpRuntime section of web.config from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, web-config

actually i need the `maxRequestLength` value of the `httpRuntime` section in web.config to check if a postedfile's size is greater. What's the best way to read it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try something like

```
HttpRuntimeSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as HttpRuntimeSection;
```

you can then get `section.MaxRequestLength`

Comment: Thanks, that works. But i've noticed that it is useless to check fot the size, because i'll get an exception if the file is greater. I think there is no (easy) way to handle that, is it?

Comment: This advice is now a bit late, but the value is that some browsers support sending a hidden value that tells it what the max size is.  The same with some uploader controls like from DevExpress.  This means you can get the # and use it to tell the UI what the limit is, and you only need to set the number once in the web.config

Answer (score 1):

On load of your page set the max file size to a client side variable and check it on a client event because if you request the server to check it obviously it will error out before it gets to your validation.