# Accessing httpRuntime maxRequestLength programmatically

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I've looked around and have yet found a way to sync between the config section for file size and the max I am allowing. Is it even possible?

Is it just best practice to allow very large file sizes in the web.config file and then enforce smaller sizes in your implementations?

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887016/how-to-access-httpruntime-section-of-web-config-from-codebehind

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
HttpRuntimeSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as HttpRuntimeSection;
```

So then you get `section.MaxRequestLength`